# Bind to an defined object of type List<T> with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

How can I do it with Ninject

```
var lst=new List<IAnimal>();
lst.Add(dog);
lst.Add(cat);

kernel.Bind<List<IAnimal>>().ToInstance(lst);
```

What shall I use Instead of `ToInstance()` as Ninject doesn't have this method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you can use `ToConstant()`:

```
kernel.Bind<List<IAnimal>>().ToConstant(lst);
```

Though you may want to consider binding `IList<IAnimal>` rather than `List<IAnimal>`.

EDIT: per your comment below

`ToMethod` is another option, depending on your requirements.  This lets you use a Factory approach, where you can return a different instance based on external factors.  For example:

```
kernel.Bind<IList<IAnimal>>().ToMethod(c => Helpers.IsDark ? return _nocturnalAnimals : return _allAnimals);
```

Comment: Can I use `ToMethod()` as well? if yes what is the difference between them?

Comment: Yes, that is another option.  `ToMethod()` allows you to use a Func<T> to return the object, rather than returning a constant value.  `ToMethod()` is essentially letting you use the Factory pattern so that you can use logic to determine what instance to return. `ToConstant()` just return the instance that you provide.